# Visual Studio 2010 and WPF: Creating a special template

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, mvvm, project-template

Is it possible to do the following in VS 2010:

- Create a new template (or something similar) so I get a XAML - view and a view model, completely with the INotifyPropertyChanged implementation and a view model invoker, all in one?
- Create a project template that gives me a view and a full view model in App.OnStartup(...) instead of this less - than - optimal "set a startup view in App.xaml"?

Comment: I think it should be standard, anyway. Most "developers" abuse WPF for a VB 6.0 replacement with bells and whistles so I think Microsoft should force MVVM down everyones throats.

Personally I would even go as far as totally remove all code - behind functionality anyway - just because the tears of ignorants and wannabes are so delicious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use MVVM light for my Silverlight, WPF and Windows Phone 7 applications. The MVVM light is a very lightweight framework to do MVVM but gives you a nice set of features, including Templates to start the projects. You can find more info on this on:   [Silverlight 4: Detect browser F5 / refresh and X / Close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3456591/silverlight-4-f5-refresh/3457817#3457817)

And at stackoverflow there is a special tag "MVVM-light" for questions about this framework.